# create a count method for user logins with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication, counter

what I want: A user logs in to his account he and automatically updates his own counter (@counter += 1).

I am new to Ruby and Rails and I am using Rails 3.2.12. I read the book "eloquent ruby", searched stackoverflow regarding this question and watched a video-ruby-course from pragmaticstudio.com. In that video-course they created a Class like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :counter
  has_secure_password
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  def initialize(counter=0)
    @counter = counter
  end

  def w00t
    @counter += 15
  end

  private
    def create_remember_token
       self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Now in my App the User log-in is settled with a SessionsController and here come my problems because every method from the User model is "unknown" to the SessionsController.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or templates_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'something went wrong.'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Here is what I already tried but didn't work for my solution: i added

```
user.w00t
```

in the SessionsController, 1 line above

```
sign_in user
```

the returned error was: "undefined methode 'w00t' for SessionsController".

I also tried to write a method in the Sessions Helper:

```
def woot(template)
  template.counter += 1    
end
```

then I re-ordered my SessionsController 'create' method like so:

```
def create
    template = Template.find_by_bosskey(params[:bession][:bosskey])
    if template
      woot template                  #that is my new line !
      tsign_in template
      redirect_back_or template
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'something went wrong.'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

With this i did not get any errors BUT still the counter doesnt change. I am more confused then ever. Please tell me WHERE to put that method or how to fix this problem for my app I am lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counter isn't being incremented because it's not being persisted to the database. Your using an instance variable which is only valid for the current request. As soon as you redirect and reload the page, that object is lost to the garbage collector, along with your counter.

To make the counter persistent you need to create a new column on user to hold the counter, then you can use the increment methods that Rails provides.

```
# create the migration

rails g migration add_sign_in_count_to_users sign_in_count:integer
rake db:migrate

# Then increment

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def w00t
    increment! :sign_in_count
  end
end
```

[ActiveRecord::Persistence#increment!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21)

Comment: You should be teaching class! Thank you so much for that answer.